# how to modify existing xml using swift for IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xmlwriter

I need some relevant solution for write xml using swift.

for example:

```
var rootElement = //get Element by XMLParser
var childElement = rootElement.child.element
childElement.text = "value changed"
```

now i want to set modified element to xml.
so i am going to write whole xml by converting rootElement to string and store in xml file.

I need such kind of XML writer with swift.

Any hint or reference would be most appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Use [NSXMLDocument](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/index.html) generate XML string.

Comment: hi i think NSXMLDocument is not available for IOS.